# System.InvalidOperationException: BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter.Init can only be called once

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an appliaciton. This has a MainActivity class. On Android if I close my app, and open Again this error message which I got.

This is my MainActivity.cs:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        DependencyService.Register<ToastNotification>();
        DependencyService.Register<OpenAppAndroid>();

        Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter.Init(this);
        ToastNotification.Init(this, new PlatformOptions() { SmallIconDrawable = Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo });

        LoadApplication(new Spirocco.App(BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter.ObtainDefaultAdapter(ApplicationContext)));

        NotificationReceiver notificationReceiver = new NotificationReceiver();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, notificationReceiver.Class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Android.App.Application.Context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        DateTime time = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
        DateTime baseTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        TimeSpan span = time.ToUniversalTime() - baseTime;
        long timer = (long)span.TotalMilliseconds;
        alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, timer, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

}

BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter.Init(this); line the application crashed by: System.InvalidOperationException: BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter.Init can only be called once. 
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Check if it is turned on before calling Init.

Comment: Which library are you using for BLE?

Comment: @Cheesebaron nexus.protocols.ble

Comment: @rokkerboci this is my question, how I can checked. Becuase local bool variable doesn't work, and BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter doesn't have static variable which tell me it's turned on or not.

Comment: @Cheesebaron https://github.com/nexussays/ble.net FYI: I briefly tried to use this one, but only the wrapper source is available, the core source code is not public and I had a number of issues that I could not fix without it.

Comment: Well, it's ugly, I know, but you could try-catch the init.. I've been searching for a method that turns off the adapter, maybe that would help, but I found nothing.

Comment: @rokkerboci Yes this is really ugly :D and doesn't working for me. The app still crashed.

Comment: @rokkerboci Sry it work's. Anybody has more nice solution? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ugly we know with @rokkerboci, but works with try-catch block.

```
try
        {
            BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter.Init(this);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
```